# Regd. The font 'ABCDEE+Calibri' contains bad/widts on Unix/Linux

Tags: java, pdfbox

Greetings for the Day :)

I am working on PdfBox and generated PDF successfully as per requirement on Windows. But when running my solution on Unix/Linux and it is generating the PDFs as per requirement. When we tried to open the PDF with Adobe Acrobat Reader DC version it is giving Pop-up **The font 'ABCDEE+Calibri' contains bad/widts**. I moved the PDF to windows from linux and tried to open the pdf , now its poping up on windows as well. I have not used calibri anywhere on my pdf. I used TrueTypeFont to load.ttc file as .ttf file. Apart from that there is no great logic as well.

```
Map<String, PDFont> suppFonts = new HashMap<>();
PDFont arial = PDType0Font.load(pddoc, <<className>>.class.getResourceAsStream("/path/to/the/file.ttf").getInputStream());
PDFont mingliu = PDType0Font.load(pddoc, new TrueTypeCollection(<<className>>.class.getResourceAsStream("/path/to/the/file.ttc").getInputStream());
suppFonts .put("arial",arial);
suppFonts .put("mingliu",mingliu);
```

we used this HashMap and retrieved font with the name we have given such as arial,mingliu..etc.

Please help me if you have faced such kind of issue earlier.

Comment: Please share the pivotal code and example pdfs.

Comment: and mention what PDFBox version you are using

Comment: Hi @Tilman Hausherr, i am using pdfBox 2.0.16 version

Comment: Hi @mkl, let me share the code which loads the fonts.

Comment: Hi@mkl, modified the question with code i used. Please let me know if i am doing anything not recommended.

Comment: *"I have not used calibri anywhere on my pdf"* - I'm afraid I have to doubt that. Pdfbox does not create font objects without being asked to, in particular not ones of system fonts like Calibri. Thus, somehow your code causes Calibri to be used. Do you probably manipulate an existing pdf or import pages from one? That could also be the source of that font.

Comment: Hi@mkl, thats true :) we are not using Calibri in our code. We are not importing any other pages also in to the file.

Comment: The current version is 2.0.19. Please retry with that one. Does your code change an existing PDF or create a new one?

Comment: Hi @TilmanHausherr, we creating new PDFs and we are not changing existing pdfs.

Comment: Then it's like mkl wrote. There's no way Calibri could be there. Unless somebody took a Calibri font file and renamed it to Arial.

Comment: Please share an example pdf. That way we can find out for what Calibri is used in your pdf, and you can look into the code responsible for that part. Ah, one other idea, is the pdf probably post-processed or manipulated by some other software after creation by your code? E.g. there was a case here on stack overflow with an overeager virus scanner damaging pdf files...